# What would be required for Orion to ferry astronauts to the ISS?

Tags: iss, orion-spacecraft, crewed-spaceflight

This mission profile seems like a no-brainer to me, but I don't recall seeing it mentioned in Orion coverage. I know this may have more to do with politics than anything else, but I'm more interested in technical points such as:

Have ISS missions been discussed internally by the Orion design team?
What remains to be done to achieve a manned rating for Orion?
Are there any current US man-rated launch vehicles capable of sending it to the ISS?
If not, what would qualifying a suitable launcher take?

Or is there some sort of non-compete clause in the CCtCAP program?

Comment: You are asking multiple questions, some of them already answered. When you have multiple questions, it is better to ask them separately.

Comment: Monstrous buckets of money. Obscenely large buckets of money.  It would take years, burning 100 dollar bills, one a second to burn that much money, to use Orion for ISS ferry duty.

Comment: Orion is definitely more spacecraft than you need for the ISS ferry mission, but if it were actually used in that role, it would go a long way toward amortizing its development cost. I'm not saying it's the best solution, mind you.

Comment: @Philipp which of the subquestions have been answered? I have no problem editing to narrow the scope.

Comment: Orion could do it, but that's not what it's designed for. It's made for longer lunar missions. Using Orion as a simple ferry would be like buying a car to cross the city when a regular taxi or public transit would work just as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orion_(spacecraft)#Orion_CEV), when Orion was conceived as part of the Constellation program, the ISS ferry role was considered; I would be surprised if that role wasn't kept in mind throughout development since then. In particular, Orion uses the ISS-compatible [NASA Docking System](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NASA_Docking_System).

Some of the excitement around the Orion EFT-1 flight was that it was "the first human-rated ship to leave LEO since Apollo"; it's not clear to me whether than meant that Orion was actually, currently human-rated or if that was stretching to cover the Orion program's overall design. In any case, human-rating is mostly a matter of "we are incorporating these necessary design features", so I would guess there's not much more to be done there.

As of [this article](http://www.ulalaunch.com/uploads/docs/Published_Papers/Human_Rating/HumanRatingAtlasVandDeltaIV.pdf) (possibly from 2008?), the Atlas and Delta launchers are very close to being human-rated, with Delta mostly needing automatic fault detection systems that could trigger an in-flight abort. Delta IV Heavy definitely has the capacity to send Orion to ISS, Atlas V probably not.

Comment: Is D4-H really powerful enough to launch Orion, with a Service module?  I do not think Orion by itself has sufficient impulse and control to dock to the ISS.  If you need the SM, D4H is not powerful enough.

Comment: Looking at Wikipedia, I think it just barely adds up; 28t to 200km LEO on D4H, Orion is 21t CM+SM and takes up to 8t service module propellant -- so we can't quite bring a full tank. Only a couple hundred ms of delta-v are needed to raise from 200km to ISS at 400km, though.

Comment: You know, you could do the orbital insertion with the service module engine. Makes getting rid of the booster more predictable.